# Im using facebook access token to post on my own page butnow im getting exception that my access token expired why?

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
{
    var responsePost = "";
    try
    {
        //create the facebook account object
        var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = message;
        responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("feed", parameters).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return responsePost;
}
```

This is the method im using for posting.
I created the access token few hours ago and it was working no problems i could post messages on my wall no problems.

And now its humping to the CATCH and throw exception:

```
(OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: Session has expired on 12 פברואר 2014 09:00. The current time is 12 פברואר 2014 14:27.

Facebook.FacebookOAuthException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=(OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: Session has expired on 12 פברואר 2014 09:00. The current time is 12 פברואר 2014 14:27.
  Source=Facebook
  ErrorCode=190
  ErrorSubcode=463
  ErrorType=OAuthException
  StackTrace:
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
       at ScrollLabelTest.Form1.PostFacebookWall(String accessToken, String message) in e:\scrolllabel\ScrollLabel\ScrollLabel\Form1.cs:line 266
  InnerException:
```

Is there any way to get access token forever ? So it wont expired anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so-called short lived Access Tokens, which expire after two hours, and so-called long-lived Access Token which expire after 60 days. There's no way to receive non-expiring ones!

Apparanty you're using short-lived Access Tokens.

So the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#termtokens and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending to see how you can exchange a short-lived to a long-lived one.