# Logging out automatically when using Graph search api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of customer numbers for which I need to fetch facebook user data using graph search api. I generated a user access token from developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and used it in my Java program which makes http get  requests using graph api for each number in my list and gets the user data. After sometime my facebook login is getting automatically logging out and I am unable to use the access token in http requests. Even after logging in and generating new user access token when I access the graph api the facebook log out is happening automatically.

Comment: Please provide some code and specify your problem carefully. Is the automated logout the problem?

Comment: I am making http get requests from java program using the user access token generated from developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/. The http request is of the form : https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=name&type=user&access_token=token. But after some requests my account being logged out automatically and thereafter I am not able to complete any http graph search request even with nely generated user access token.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting "logged out", but the Access Token is likely to be outdated. Probably you are using an so-called short lived Access Token, which is valid for two hours. The Graph API Explorer generates such kind of Token. But there's the possibility to exchange the short-lived ones to so-called long lived ones (valid for 60 days) via an Graph API endpoint.

See my answer here: [Im using facebook access token to post on my own page butnow im getting exception that my access token expired why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741284/im-using-facebook-access-token-to-post-on-my-own-page-butnow-im-getting-exceptio/21748303#21748303)

Comment: It is not about shortlived token or long lived token  because I have tried with long lived token also. My account is getting automatically logged out after some requests. Because when I access facebook.com from my browser it takes me to login page again.

Comment: OK, but imho the Graph API Explorer always generates a short lived token. What is the error message you get from the Graph API?

Comment: access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error

Comment: complete message is : {
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}

Comment: how can I prevent automatic log out which invalidates the user access token whether short lived or long lived token and requests fail.